# How to route to a belongs_to object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller method that creates a user.  I want it to route to user preferences when the user creates himself.  How do I write the path?  Here's the method:

```
 def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
     redirect_to profiles_path, :notice => "Signed up!"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

Comment: What does your routes look like?

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume that when the users creates himself you want it to redirect to an edit option of this users preferences. Now, if the users is not created, there cant be any preferences to it. So im thinking that, once the users saves, you should create a record in the 'preferences' model, with the user_id so you know where to redirect to. (This is assuming that the @preferences model has a user_id field).

Something like:

```
 if @user.save
     @preferences.new
     @preferences.user_id = @user.id
     @preferences.save
     redirect_to edit_preferences_path(:user_id=> @user.id), :notice => "Signed up!"
 else
     whatever
 end
```

Hope it helps.